# ping response shows it is from a different mac address

Tags: linux, networking

I've been having this weird occurrence about ping.

The setup is:

- `Unit A` : Windows OS

  - virtIO `adapter1` with IP `1.2.3.4` and MAC `a.b.c.d.e.f`
  - virtIO `adapter2` with IP `5.6.7.8` and MAC `g.h.i.j.k.l`
- `Unit B` : Red Hat OS

  - IP `2.4.6.8` and MAC `m.n.o.p.q.r`

Inside terminal of Red Hat OS, we ping the IP address of the virtIO adapter.

I cannot understand why :

1. duplicate ping responses occurs, either alternatively or every other 2 ping requests.
2. I've done tracedump while doing the ping and noticeably the response MAC address is **NOT** that of the MAC Address of the ping-requested IP.

When running `ping 1.2.3.4` :

```
PING REQ m.n.o.p.q.r > a.b.c.d.e.f  :: 2.4.6.8 > 1.2.3.4
PING RES g.h.i.j.k.l > m.n.o.p.q :: 1.2.3.4 > 2.4.6.8
PING RES g.h.i.j.k.l > m.n.o.p.q :: 1.2.3.4 > 2.4.6.8  DUP!
```

I've done `arp -an` and the arp table entries were correct according to the specified IP-to-MAC relationship...

What could cause such occurrence? Would it be some misconfiguration in the network between the two units?

**Edit**

Here are the exact details of my network setup... modified the mac addresses; the "m.n.o" prefixes represents the similarities I saw when doing the commands in the units.

`Unit B` details where we do the ping request.

`ifconfig -a` :

```
ctrl: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
    inet 10.0.2.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::f427:50ff:fe58:b132  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether **aa:bb:cc:ee:dd:ee**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

ctrlpub0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.40.90.151  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe71:6754  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether **m.n.o.71.67.54**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

ctrlpub1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.40.90.183  netmask 255.255.255.224  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe52:a3d4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether **m:n:o:52:ad:34**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>

oam: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
    inet 10.0.0.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::641d:cfff:feac:1129  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether **aa.bb.cc.dd.ee.ff**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

`arp -an` :

```
? (10.40.90.131) at **m.n.o.p.q.r** [ether] on ctrlpub0 <--- so this is the one that we ping to...
? (10.0.0.3) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on oam
? (10.0.2.102) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on ctrl
? (10.0.2.101) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on ctrl
? (10.40.90.158) at **g.h.i.j.k.l** [ether] on ctrlpub0 <--- but this is the mac address in the reply, and yes it is not starting with the m.n.o. prefix ...
? (10.0.0.11) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on oam
? (10.0.2.90) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on ctrl
? (10.0.0.100) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on oam
? (10.0.0.1) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on oam
? (10.0.2.103) at X:X:X:X:X:X [ether] on ctrl
```

In the windows OS, `Unit A` :

```
PWindows IP Configuration

  Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : GEN162401
  Primary Dns Suffix . . . . . . . . . . .  : 
  Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
  IP Routing Enabled . . . . . . . . . . .  : No
  WINS Proxy Enabled . . . . . . . . . . .  : No

Ethernet Adapter EXT-CP2-EL5:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . .  :
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #5
  Physical Address . . . . . . . . . . . .  : m:n:o:D5:5d:FC
  DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : No
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . . . . . : Yes
  IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : 10.40.90.163(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
  NetBIOS over Tcpip . . . . . . . . . . .  : Enabled

Ethernet Adapter EXT-CP1-EL4: 

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . .  :
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter #4
  Physical Address . . . . . . . . . . . .  : **m:n:o:p:q:r**  <---- **this is the one we are pinging to**
  DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : No
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . . . . . : Yes
  IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : 10.40.90.131(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . . . . . :
  NetBIOS over Tcpip . . . . . . . . . . .  : Enabled

Ethernet Adapter OnM:

  Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . .  :
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter
  Physical Address . . . . . . . . . . . .  : m:n:o:78:55:AA
  DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : No
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . . . . . : Yes
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . . . . . : fe80:f0c1:45d2:5417:a8c3%5(Preferred)
  IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  : 172.24.17.100(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.24.17.1
  DNS Servers . . . . . . . . .  . . . . .  : fec0:0:0:ffff:1%1
                                              fec0:0:0:ffff:2%1
                                              fec0:0:0:ffff:3%1
  NetBIOS over Tcpip . . . . . . . . . . .  : Enabled
```

Doing a `ping 10.40.90.131` yields:

```
  12:39:13.896547 **m.n.o.71.67.54** > **m:n:o:p:q:r**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.151 > 10.40.90.131: ICMP echo request, id 843, seq 1, length 64
  12:39:13.897344 **g.h.i.j.k.l** > **m.n.o.71.67.54**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.131 > 10.40.90.151: ICMP echo reply, id 843, seq 1, length 64
  12:39:14.897181 **m.n.o.71.67.54** > **m:n:o:p:q:r**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.151 > 10.40.90.131: ICMP echo request, id 843, seq 2, length 64
  12:39:14.897500 **g.h.i.j.k.l** > **m.n.o.71.67.54**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.131 > 10.40.90.151: ICMP echo reply, id 843, seq 2, length 64
  12:39:15.897284 **m.n.o.71.67.54** > **m:n:o:p:q:r**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.151 > 10.40.90.131: ICMP echo request, id 843, seq 3, length 64
  12:39:15.897633 **g.h.i.j.k.l** > **m.n.o.71.67.54**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.131 > 10.40.90.151: ICMP echo reply, id 843, seq 3, length 64
  12:39:16.897243 **m.n.o.71.67.54** > **m:n:o:p:q:r**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.151 > 10.40.90.131: ICMP echo request, id 843, seq 4, length 64
  12:39:16.897483 **g.h.i.j.k.l** > **m.n.o.71.67.54**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.131 > 10.40.90.151: ICMP echo reply, id 843, seq 4, length 64
  12:39:17.260557 **g.h.i.j.k.l** > **m.n.o.71.67.54**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.131 > 10.40.90.151: ICMP echo reply, id 843, seq 4, length 64
```

Comment: What are the network masks of your interfaces ? If you have multiple addresses with different adresses on the same network, [the behaviour of outgoing packets in OSes such as Windows or Linux is undefined](http://wiki.treck.com/Appendix_C%3a_Strong_End_System_Model_/_Weak_End_System_Model) (and this behaviour could be expected, because packets will always go out through the same interface).

Comment: If both `VirtIO` adapters are on the same network, `Unit A` can use either of them to send the reply packet. There's no requirement that it send from the adapter with the IP address you pinged.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the info. Does this hold true if the adapters are only in one unit?

Comment: @Barmar: in his example, adapters are not in the same network (which would be bad practice). However it looks like there is an extra address assigned on one of the interfaces, which could cause this behaviour.

Comment: It looks like `10.40.90.131` is also assigned on the VM **host** (because the MAC address is one of an HP NIC), and the VM **host** replies by itself. That or/and the VM **host** is behaving as an ARP proxy and is replying to requests for the adapter's address with **its own MAC address**. `10.40.90.158` could be an address assigned on the VM **host**.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the IP addresses imply the devices are not in the same subnet. If the devices are not in the same subnet they would communicate via their default gateways.

Packets that pass through routers/default gateways will have their ethernet header stripped and rebuild. Causing the src mac you see to be the mac of the router / L3 forwarding device the IP packet last passed through.

Also, you are seeing duplicate responses so it is also possible you have
2 devices on the same network (broadcast domain) with duplicated IP address configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Hmmm that was what I thought at first about the units not being in the same subnet, but I'm not really sure after I did the traceddump. it shows that Unit B > Unit A (10.40.90.151 > 10.40.90.131)

I've edited the post with more specific details. But yeah there must be something that I really misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `10.10.90.158` is assigned on the same host (on a different interface) as `10.40.90.131`. However, I cannot find this address in the configuration you pasted.

If this is the case, as these interfaces are both in the same network, the host has absolutely no way to tell which one to use when sending out a packet, because of the implications of a "weak end networking stack". Because of this, the packet goes out on the other interface, even if you'd have expected it to go out on the same interface as it came in.

You cannot assign multiple addresses on overlapping networks on multiple interfaces on such systems (Windows, Mac OS, Linux, anything not specific really).

**EDIT**: More simply, are you sure you don't have extra addresses on `EXT-CP1-EL4` ?

Comment: yes. I did ipconfig /all and it only showed as what I have pasted.

Your insight about this is promisin;! I will try to see if there is any way to see "who" is this 10.40.90.158

Also I've tried pinging the other virtIO interface, and the duplicate also occurs and with a "twin" ip MAC address... pretty much the same nature as with 10.40.90.131

Comment: The last two packets in your dump have the same ICMP sequence number and source MAC. I can't understand why would this be happening, unless you have a Layer1 problem or MAC conflicts. (Also, the duplicate packet came much later (350ms), which is weird. Maybe there are ARP proxies involved in your network, sitting at ~175 ms ?). How did you capture traffic (just ICMP ? would it be possible to send a `pcap` dump somewhere ?)

Comment: Yes it is really weird. Anyways here is what I've captured at the ping requester machine. For this one I've first cleared up the arp table of this unit so that it'll start clean.
https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/1e8dbc95f7bb

Answer (score 0):

12:39:16.897483 **g.h.i.j.k.l** > **m.n.o.71.67.54**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.131 > 10.40.90.151: ICMP echo reply, id 843, seq 4, length 64
  12:39:17.260557 **g.h.i.j.k.l** > **m.n.o.71.67.54**, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.40.90.131 > 10.40.90.151: ICMP echo reply, id 843, seq 4, length 64

In your updated out shows the two packets you mention coming from same src ip and same src mac. Packets could be duplicated by switches/bridges flooding in the path between the 2 hosts. Do you possibility have some virtual ethernet bridge (brctl) or real switches in the path between the hosts? Could they be forming a loop?